# Apache Nifi RouteHL7 Issue

Tags: hl7, apache-nifi

I am unable to understand how to use RouteHL7 processor in nifi, Can any one please guide me how to use that.

I want to add some property in RouteHL7 Processor. Please guide me how to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You add properties to the `RouteHL7` processor the same way as for any other processor. There is a "**+**" button on the top right of the *Properties* tab of the *Configure Processor* dialog (right click on the processor and select *Configure*).

[image: Adding a new property]

You then name the property (this will be the name of the connection relationship for any flowfiles that match) and provide your query value. For example:

`glucose`: `DECLARE result AS REQUIRED OBX SELECT MESSAGE WHERE result.4 < 60`

[image: Glucose filter property]

Then drag the connection from the `RouteHL7` processor to your desired destination and select `glucose` as the relationship to route there.

I've posted [this template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/9b46011185efd0380e6c5da0a3412e8f) as a Gist, and you can look at the [unit tests](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-commons/nifi-hl7-query-language/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/hl7/query/TestHL7Query.java) for `RouteHL7` to see other query examples.

[image: Apache NiFi RouteHL7 Flow]

Comment: Thank you, will try for that.